# Align values of css attributes with eslint or stylelint

Tags: css, eslint, stylelint

```
.backend-layout {
  background-image:       linear-gradient(to bottom, white, #ccc);
  display:                grid;
  grid-template-columns:  auto;
  grid-template-rows:     0 40px minmax(40vh, 100vh) 40px;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

is it possible to align `height`  value with other attributes of the class automatically (--fix option) via **eslint** or **stylelint**?

Dmitry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to align height value with other attributes of the class automatically (--fix option) via eslint or stylelint?

There isn't a built-in rule in stylelint to do this.

I don't believe ESLint can do this either as it is used to lint JavaScript, rather than CSS.

However, stylelint is extensible via [its plugin system](https://stylelint.io/developer-guide/plugins/). You can create a plugin for this specific use case.

As per [this discussion in the stylelint issue tracker](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/issues/769), you could call your plugin `stylelint-declaration-block-no-misaligned-values`. It would ensure that all the values within a declaration block beginning at the same column number.